# How to perform calculation based on ratio condition in scala

Tags: scala

I'm attempting to learn `scala` and came across a problem to solve. I have an input which is a map of items: `Map(Apples -> 3, Soup -> 2, Bread -> 2)`. I'm finding the last bit of the problem a bit tricky.

How do I calculate the total cost of bread, given that it's normal price is 0.8 but for every 2 soups, 1 bread cost 0.5.

So for example:

```
val prices: Map[String, Double] = Map(
    "Soup" -> 0.65,
    "Bread" -> 0.80,
    "Milk" -> 1.30,
    "Apples" -> 1.00
)

itemCounts = Map(Apples -> 3, Soup -> 2, Bread -> 2) // the input

applesTotal = 3 // (1*3)
soupTotal = 1.3 // (0.65*2)
breadTotal = 1.3 // (0.8 + (0.5*1)) - given that for every 2 soups 1 bread cost 0.5
total = 5.6
```

So far my code is:

```
    // Get bread discount
    val soupCount = itemCounts.getOrElse("Soup", 0)
    val breadCount = itemCounts.getOrElse("Bread", 0)

    val breadPrice = prices.getOrElse("Bread", 0.0)
    val breadDiscount = 0.5

    // Where I need to adjust the code
    if (soupCount / breadCount.toDouble == 2.0/1.0) {
      val breadPrice = prices.getOrElse("Bread", 0.0)
      val adjustedBreadPrice = breadPrice + 0.5
      println(s"The cost of bread is: ${breadCount * adjustedBreadPrice}")
    }
```

I thought I could try and do this by checking if the ratio of `soup:bread` is `2:1` but this doesn't seem to be the right way forward. Because if there is 4 soups and 3 breads, that is not getting covered by the condition and the correct value would be `4.4` - (0.65 x 4 + (0.5 x 2) + 0.8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. How much total bread?

   ```
   val bread = itemCounts.getOrElse("Bread", 0)
   ```
2. What part of it is discounted?

   ```
   val discounted = itemCounts.getOrElse("Soup", 0).map(_ /2) min bread
   ```
3. What's left?

   ```
   val remaining = (bread - discounted) max 0
   ```
4. What's the total price?

   ```
   val breadPrice = remaining * prices.getOrElse("Bread", 0) + discounted*0.5
   ```

Comment: Awsome, this works! Very simple too. Thanks a lot